# Can not connect to Object Explorer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have updated from windows 8 to windows 10 recently. My SQL server was running perfectly after updating. But as i installed further updates in my laptop, SQL server eventually stopped and started showing this message as I use to connect its object explorer:
  [image]

My hostname is IQRA and I am entering this  as i connect:
[image]

Anyone please help me to resolve this issue in some easy way. I found so many methods on internet but nothing helped me out!

Comment: well what have you tried? It looks as if you are using the wrong instance or server name... or entering something that isn't expected, so let us know what you are entering.

Comment: I have edited my question. please check it again @scsimon

Comment: have you tried using SQL authentication and using a db account?

Comment: No. I have never tried this. how can i make a db account

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something might have triggered SQL Server to stop. Have you checked the Task Manager to see if the server is running?

[image]

In case you are unfamiliar with it:

- Open Task Manager.
- Click the Services Tab.
- Look for the SQL Server instance and make sure it is **Running**.
- If not, right click then choose **Start**.